# Get the major version number of OS using command prompt

Tags: windows, command-line

I am checking for the OS version using command prompt.

I am using following code to get the version number

```
systeminfo | findstr /B /c:"OS Version"
```

### Output

#### For Windows Server 2003

```
OS Version:                5.2.3790 Service Pack 2 Build 3790
```

#### For Windows 7

```
OS Version:                6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
```

But I am not sure how can I have Major version number (First digit of version)

How can I get the major version number OR

If can I check if the version numbers first char is 5 OR 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pipe the output again through FINDSTR, for example:

```
systeminfo | findstr /B /c:"OS Version" | findstr /c:" 6."
```

And then check the [ERRORLEVEL](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/09/26/8965755.aspx) returned to see if `6.` was present in the returned string.

NOTE:

1. I've put a space at the beginning of the second string to try and ensure that it doesn't match against anything else that might be stuffed into the output from systeminfo on an "OS Version" line
2. This is really brittle as it relies on the format of the returned text from systeminfo
3. There's doubtless a better way to do this with the VER command
4. For a really robust way of doing this that is independent of the format of the text returned by systeminfo/ver, consider writing a small program in C# (Express Edition is free) that looks at the [`System.Environment.OSVersion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.osversion(v=vs.110).aspx) property and sets an error level for you as this would be string parse-free (and thus a lot less likely to break)!

Answer (score 1):

here is a snippet using ver.exe :

```
for /f "tokens=4 delims=. " %%i in ('ver') do set majorversion=%%i
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `ver` command instead of `systeminfo`. My Windows 7 machine reports:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
```

The following batch script snippet will define a variable containing the primary version number:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%A in ('ver') do for /f "tokens=2 delims=. " %%B in ("%%A") do set "majorVersion=%%B"
```

Comment: What If I want to have first 3 digit